# Stopping subprocess executing in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, mplayer

I'm trying to play a series of Audio files through MPlayer which is classed as a subprocess in Python.

Then when the .stop() command is called. I want the subprocess to..... well.. stop executing.

The important thing I want to keep occurring is the main thread. I don't want Python to terminate altogether.

Below is the code I have tried out so far.

```
class Alarm:

    urllib.request.urlretrieve(Settings.news_url, 'news.mp3')

    tts1 = gTTS(text='Good morning' + Settings.name + 'It is ' + str(date.today()), lang='en')
    tts2 = gTTS(text='Here is the latest news from the BBC world service', lang='en')
    tts3 = gTTS(text='The weather for today is ' + Settings.weather_rss.entries[0]['title'].split(' ', 1)[1], lang='en')
    tts4 = gTTS(text='That is all for now. Have a great day!', lang='en')

    tts1.save(Settings.greeting)
    tts2.save(Settings.news_intro)
    tts3.save(Settings.weather_forecast)
    tts4.save(Settings.outtro)


    def play(self):     
        alarmpi = subprocess.call(['mplayer', Settings.greeting, Settings.news_intro, 'news.mp3', Settings.weather_forecast, Settings.outtro]);

    def stop(self):
        alarmpi.kill()

alarm = Alarm()

on = Thread(target=alarm.play)
stop = Thread(target=alarm.stop)
on.start()
time.sleep(5)
stop.start()
```

However when I run this, I get an error saying alarmpi is not defined.

Is there a different way to tackle this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just define `alarmpi` as a *member* of the class using `self` object to store it so you can recall it in the `stop` method (define it first in the class constructor so you can call `stop` without calling `play` first)

```
def __init__(self):
    self.alarmpi = None

def play(self):     
    self.alarmpi = subprocess.call(['mplayer', Settings.greeting, Settings.news_intro, 'news.mp3', Settings.weather_forecast, Settings.outtro]);

def stop(self):
    if self.alarmpi:
        self.alarmpi.kill()
        self.alarmpi = None
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Now im getting an attribute error.

AttributeError: 'Alarm' object has no attribute 'alarmpi''

Comment: are you sure you changed the `play` method? cause it works for me here.

Comment: Ah yes.. just retyped the application and it works as expected :) Thank you!